# How to make an image with transparent text on an opaque background?

Tags: gimp, transparency

For my blog, I would like to create something like this logo:

[image: ReadWrite logo]

However, where the text on the image above is white, I would like to have a transparent hole instead, so that the background of the page would show through.  How could I create something like that in GIMP?

Comment: I tried setting text on transparent background. It just leave text that can be used on any background. But the question which is asked is different. Here I need to make a hole (characters) that is see through on transparent layer.

Comment: Why it is not a valid question?

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer that you're not asking for us to design a logo for you, but simply how to achieve the transparency effect you want. At least, I _assume_ that's what you're asking. (For the logo design, you're on your own; requests for free design work are off topic here.)

Comment: Thank you for rephrasing the question. You got it right. Asking for logo design is too much of asking. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you could do that, but the obvious choice for me would be to use a [layer mask](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-mask-add.html).

First, make a layer filled with your desired color:

[image: A blue rectangle]

Next, use *Layer → Mask → Add Layer Mask..* to add a fully opaque mask for the layer.

Then create the text or other shape you want to cut out from the image, e.g. some text, as black on white:

[image: The word "TESTING" as black text on white]

Finally, copy the text and paste it into the layer mask.  Your color layer should now have a transparent text-shaped hole in it:

[image: Transparent text on blue background]

There are many other possible ways to achieve the same result, e.g. using *Color to Alpha* or just by selecting the text by color and cutting the resulting selection out of the color layer.  The nice thing about layer masks, however, is that the mask and the content of the layer remain separately editable, allowing you to easily adjust them later.

Comment: Just read it. Will test it tomorrow and respond. Thanks.

Comment: "Then create text or other shape ...". Is this a new image with that property (background white and text)? I tried that and it looks like this in GIMP: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/xBtvMUzr5Uuo8fgejNa0nI6v9GhZF9w_-sCbpednZLc?full-exif=true but in browser it is this https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/e2gflxjthNEQqoiaih6iK46v9GhZF9w_-sCbpednZLc?full-exif=true

Comment: I think only video guide can help me. If you find any video on youtube then please add. For me searching is very tough as I am new to this. Difficult to get keyword. +1

Comment: How is a video going to be any different then what is posted above unless you are looking for someone to do it for you?  If you are having issues with the above why not edit your question and show what effort you have done and what areas you're struggling so someone can provide you the right answer?